# Unable to get Public Key in c# is public key uses ECC

Tags: c#, public-key, x509certificate2

I can't get public key size of x509certificate in c# if public key is ECC. If public key is RSA, we can get is using PublicKey.Key.Keysize But this does not work if its ECC. We can get ANS encoded parameters if public key algorithm is ECC, but not sure if and how can we get key size for than. Is there any way i can get key size if public key is ECC ?

Comment: Please post the code you already have which is not working to give us a place to start.